# Hide complex column with colspan and rowspan with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building more or less a complex table with a lot of *colspan* and *rowspan* `td`'s. Now i would like to create an onclick event on those pink column. So as soon as you click on one of these `+` column with class `collapse`, i would like to hide columns. For example, when I click the first `+`, I would like to hide the whole *First driver* column including *Driver Name*, *first-driver-01*, *Driver ID*, etc.

[image]

`nth-child(x)` is not helping really, because it does not ignore the *col- and rowspans*. I tried to group the `td`'s in a seperated tag, like this:

```
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">CIM</td>
        <!-- First driver -->
        <group class="first-driver-01">
            <td colspan="4">First driver</td>
        </group>
        <td rowspan="3" class="collapse">+</td>
        <group class="second-driver-213">
            <td colspan="4">Second driver</td>
        </group>
        <td rowspan="3" class="collapse">+</td>
    </tr>
```

Unfortunately my chrome browser does this to the tags:

[image]

Comment: You could add a class to every one of those table cells you want to hide.

Comment: @Blazemonger This was like my last way out, but it did the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use div's and CSS for something like this and style them like a table. I'm not going to re-create your entire table but here is an example I made using a smaller table, I'll leave you to have some fun.

Javascript

```
document.getElementById("clickme").onclick = function(){
      var divsToHide = document.getElementsByClassName("hide"); //divsToHide is an array
    if(document.getElementById("clickme").innerHTML == "-"){
    for(var i = 0; i < divsToHide.length; i++){
        divsToHide[i].style.visibility = "hidden"; // or
        divsToHide[i].style.display = "none"; // depending on what you're doing
        } 
       document.getElementById("clickme").innerHTML = "+"
    }
    else {
           for(var i = 0; i < divsToHide.length; i++){
            divsToHide[i].style.visibility = "visible"; // or
            divsToHide[i].style.display = "table-cell"; // depending on what you're doing
          } 
           document.getElementById("clickme").innerHTML = "-"

        }
};
```

HTML

```
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell header">Team</div>
    <div class="cell header">Wins</div>
    <div class="cell header">Losses</div>
    <div class="cell header hide ">Pct</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">Bulls</div>
    <div class="cell">29</div>
    <div class="cell">18</div>
    <div class="cell hide">.617</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">Pacers</div>
    <div class="cell">28</div>
    <div class="cell">19</div>
    <div class="cell hide">.596</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell" id="clickme">-</div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.table {
    display:table;
}
.row {
    display:table-row;
}
.cell {
    display:table-cell;
    padding:2px;
}
.header {
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
}
```

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/RFWT5/10/)

I hope this helps,
Good luck

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did it differently, because the table structure got really complicated. I just added to every cell a class with a group id.

Comment: ahh glad to see you got it working, and no problem. Please accept the answer if it helped you.